# Cannot use errors.New("something wrong") (type error) as type error in return argument

Tags: go

i have the following code (http://play.golang.org/p/47rvtGqGFn). it works on playground but fail on my system

```
 package main

import (
   "log"
   "errors" 
)

func main() {
    j := &JustForTest{}
    a, err := j.Test(3)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    log.Println(a)
}

type JustForTest struct {}

func (j *JustForTest) Test(i int) (string, error) {
    if i < 5 {
        return "fail", errors.New("something wrong")
    }
    return "success", nil
}
```

in playground it return something i expected :

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 something wrong
2009/11/10 23:00:00 fail
```

But when I run "go install" on my system, I get compiler error :

```
../warehouse/warehouse.go:32: cannot convert nil to type error
../warehouse/warehouse.go:83: cannot use errors.New("something wrong") (type error) as type error in return argument
../warehouse/warehouse.go:85: cannot use nil as type error in return argument
```

I feel this is really weird. I have upgrade my Go installation from 1.3.2 to 1.3.3 but still i get the same error. What could possibly wrong with my system?

**UPDATE:**
Here's my local code :

```
package warehouse

import (
    "net/http"
    "path"
    "log"
    "errors"
)


func Route(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {


    uri := path.Dir(r.URL.Path)

    base := path.Base(r.URL.Path)
    if uri == "/" || (uri == "/products" && base != "products") {
        uri = path.Join(uri, base)
    }

    // initiate all types
    warehouse := Warehouse{}
    inventory := Inventory{}

    // check the request method
    if r.Method == "GET" {
        switch uri {
        case "/warehouse":
            j := &JustForTest{}     // This is the troubled code
            a, err := j.Test(3)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
            }
            log.Println(a)
            ...
       }
} 

type JustForTest struct {}

func (j *JustForTest) Test(i int) (string, error) {
    if i < 5 {
        return "fail", errors.New("something wrong")
    }
    return "success", nil
}
```

I found that when i run this code, I get the error. But when I write a new fresh package and just write the exactly the same code as i did in the plaground. it works. I don't understand why this is happening. any advice guys?

Comment: The code you tested locally obviously is different from the one you posted. You are getting errors on lines not present in the example.

Comment: Still not your code. Doesn't compile, where are Warehouse and Inventory? There is no line 85. It looks like the problem is in warehouse.go file, not here.

Comment: @siritinga I agree with you, something in my package (other file) just affected how the type error work. I found mr. tomwilde answer is my solution. Thanks for the clue anyway

Comment: What about using `return "fail", fmt.Errorf("something wrong")` instead of `return "fail", errors.New("something wrong")`. You would have to import "fmt" and remove "errors" package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have defined a type called `error` in your package.

That's causing a name-collision with the built-in `error` type (your package-defined type shadows the built-in type) and hence the confusing error message you're seeing.

Use a different, more descriptive (less-general) name for your package's type.

Comment: nice catch dude. that's exactly the cause of my headache. You are right, i have define an new error type somewhere in my code two weeks ago, and sadly i really forgot about it. it obviously override go's default error type. now i found it. it solve. thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @tomwilde response, I would recommend using [`fmt.Errorf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Errorf) function to build errors. You would also need to add import of "fmt" package and could remove import of "errors" package.

Your code could be changed from:

```
if i < 5 {
    return "fail", errors.New("something wrong")
}
```

To:

```
if i < 5 {
    return "fail", fmt.Errorf("something wrong")
}
```

Advantage of using `fmt.Errorf()` approach is that you can also provide formatting to build your error message, which might be very handy in the future e.g. `fmt.Errorf("some error .... %#v", aValue)`

I hope that will help.

Comment: nice. this is useful for me since i already import and use fmt :). thanks